# Waiting loop alternative in c++ thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have implemented a simple thread pool in my program where the main thread sets the data and notify the threads to execute and then wait in a loop for them to finish.

```
while(true){

// set the data
....
// notify threads
...
while(n_done < num_threads){}        // wait in the while loop for threads to finish

}
```

Each thread takes approx  10-15 ms to complete until then the main thread just keeps looping for threads to finish consuming a lot of cpu usage.
Is there any alternative method to stop or sleep the main thread execution until the threads complete without a loop.

Comment: I don't have time to give this a proper answer, but look up how some commercial-quality thread pool implementations return a `Future` object for each task that is submitted to the pool. The caller that submits a task can later use the `Future` instance to wait until the task is completed, and possibly get a return value that was computed by the task. If your thread pool returned futures, then your main thread could first collect all of the futures into a list as it submits the tasks, and then it could await each future in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for all thread to finish and not reuse them you can use `join()` on every thread at the end.

Comment: But the threads do not end, they are being used again and again.